# Conditions to make unitary a given matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra, complex

Suppose I have some symmetric matrix `W = {{c[1, 1], c[1, 2], c[1, 3]}, {c[1, 2], c[2, 2],c[2, 3]}, {c[1, 3], c[2, 3], c[3, 3]}};` where the c's are complex and I want conditions on them such that W is unitary.
I tried using with `Solve[ConjugateTranspose[W].W-IdentityMatrix[3]==0]` but seems like the equations are to heavy to solve. Is there another way to do this? I just want conditions on the c's.

Comment: The conditions are, quite literally, $WW^\dagger=1$, component-wise. It's not likely this can be simplified any further. You could try something like `Reduce@And@@Flatten@ ...`, but don't expect any considerable simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very complex problem in general. I'll do the $n=2$ case only.

Define the matrix $W$ with explicit real and imaginary parts: $c_{i,j}=a_{i,j}+i b_{i,j}$,

```
n = 2;
W = Table[c[Min[i, j], Max[i, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}] /. c[i_, j_] -> a[i, j] + I*b[i, j]
Wd = ConjugateTranspose[W] // ComplexExpand
```

[image]

[image]

The variables of $W$:

```
vars = Flatten[Table[{a[i, j], b[i, j]}, {i, n}, {j, i, n}]]
(*    {a[1, 1], b[1, 1], a[1, 2], b[1, 2], a[2, 2], b[2, 2]}    *)
```

Set the real and imaginary parts of $W\cdot W^{\dagger}-1$ to zero and reduce over the reals:

```
Reduce[Thread[Flatten[ComplexExpand[ReIm[W.Wd - IdentityMatrix[n]]]] == 0],
       vars, Reals]
```

> (a[1, 1] == -1 && b[1, 1] == 0 && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>      b[1, 2] == 
>       0 && ((a[2, 2] == -1 && 
>          b[2, 2] == 0) || (-1 < a[2, 2] < 
>           1 && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2] || 
>            b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 2] == 1 && 
>          b[2, 2] == 0))) || (-1 < 
>       a[1, 1] < -(1/Sqrt[
>        2]) && ((b[1, 1] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (-Sqrt[
>            1 - a[1, 1]^2] < b[1, 1] <= 0 && 
>          a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] == 
>               Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (0 < 
>           b[1, 1] < Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && 
>          a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] ==
>                Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (b[1, 
>            1] == Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))))) || (a[1, 
>        1] == -(1/Sqrt[
>        2]) && ((b[1, 1] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (-Sqrt[
>            1 - a[1, 1]^2] < b[1, 1] <= 
>           Root[-1 + 6 a[1, 1]^2 - 12 a[1, 1]^4 + 
>              8 a[1, 1]^6 + (-2 - 12 a[1, 1]^2 + 18 a[1, 1]^4 + 
>                 a[1, 1]^6) #1^2 + (12 a[1, 1]^2 + 
>                 3 a[1, 1]^4) #1^4 + (2 + 3 a[1, 1]^2) #1^6 + #1^8 &, 
>            3] && a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] == 
>               Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (Root[-1 + 6 a[1, 1]^2 - 
>              12 a[1, 1]^4 + 
>              8 a[1, 1]^6 + (-2 - 12 a[1, 1]^2 + 18 a[1, 1]^4 + 
>                 a[1, 1]^6) #1^2 + (12 a[1, 1]^2 + 
>                 3 a[1, 1]^4) #1^4 + (2 + 3 a[1, 1]^2) #1^6 + #1^8 &, 
>            3] < b[1, 1] < Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && 
>          a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] ==
>                Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (b[1, 
>            1] == Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))))) || (-(1/
>        Sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2muA.png)) < a[1, 1] < 1/Sqrt[
>       2] && ((b[1, 1] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (-Sqrt[
>            1 - a[1, 1]^2] < b[1, 1] <= 0 && 
>          a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] == 
>               Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (0 < 
>           b[1, 1] < Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && 
>          a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] ==
>                Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (b[1, 
>            1] == Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))))) || (a[1, 
>        1] == 1/Sqrt[
>       2] && ((b[1, 1] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (-Sqrt[
>            1 - a[1, 1]^2] < b[1, 1] <= 
>           Root[-1 + 6 a[1, 1]^2 - 12 a[1, 1]^4 + 
>              8 a[1, 1]^6 + (-2 - 12 a[1, 1]^2 + 18 a[1, 1]^4 + 
>                 a[1, 1]^6) #1^2 + (12 a[1, 1]^2 + 
>                 3 a[1, 1]^4) #1^4 + (2 + 3 a[1, 1]^2) #1^6 + #1^8 &, 
>            3] && a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] == 
>               Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (Root[-1 + 6 a[1, 1]^2 - 
>              12 a[1, 1]^4 + 
>              8 a[1, 1]^6 + (-2 - 12 a[1, 1]^2 + 18 a[1, 1]^4 + 
>                 a[1, 1]^6) #1^2 + (12 a[1, 1]^2 + 
>                 3 a[1, 1]^4) #1^4 + (2 + 3 a[1, 1]^2) #1^6 + #1^8 &, 
>            3] < b[1, 1] < Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && 
>          a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] ==
>                Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (b[1, 
>            1] == Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 
>             1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))))) || (1/Sqrt[
>       2] < a[1, 1] < 
>       1 && ((b[1, 1] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (-Sqrt[
>            1 - a[1, 1]^2] < b[1, 1] <= 0 && 
>          a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] == 
>               Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (0 < 
>           b[1, 1] < Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && 
>          a[1, 2] == 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (b[1, 2] ==
>                Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && a[2, 2] == a[1, 1] && 
>              b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))) || (b[1, 
>            1] == Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>          b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 1]^2] && ((a[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]) || (-Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] < 
>               a[2, 2] < Sqrt[
>               1 - b[1, 
>                 2]^2] && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2] ||
>                 b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 
>                2] == Sqrt[1 - b[1, 2]^2] && 
>              b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2 - b[1, 2]^2]))))) || (a[1, 
>        1] == 1 && b[1, 1] == 0 && a[1, 2] == 0 && 
>      b[1, 2] == 
>       0 && ((a[2, 2] == -1 && 
>          b[2, 2] == 0) || (-1 < a[2, 2] < 
>           1 && (b[2, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2] || 
>            b[2, 2] == Sqrt[1 - a[2, 2]^2])) || (a[2, 2] == 1 && 
>          b[2, 2] == 0))) || (-1 < a[1, 1] < 1 && -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2] < 
>       b[1, 1] < Sqrt[
>       1 - a[1, 
>         1]^2] && ((a[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>          b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - a[1, 2]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>          a[2, 2] == (-a[1, 1] a[1, 2]^2 - 2 a[1, 2] b[1, 1] b[1, 2] + 
>            a[1, 1] b[1, 2]^2)/(
>           a[1, 2]^2 + b[1, 2]^2)) || (-Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] <
>            a[1, 2] < 
>           0 && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[
>                1 - a[1, 1]^2 - a[1, 2]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == (-a[1, 1] a[1, 2]^2 - 
>                2 a[1, 2] b[1, 1] b[1, 2] + a[1, 1] b[1, 2]^2)/(
>               a[1, 2]^2 + b[1, 2]^2)) || (b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[1, 1]^2 - a[1, 2]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == (-a[1, 1] a[1, 2]^2 - 
>                2 a[1, 2] b[1, 1] b[1, 2] + a[1, 1] b[1, 2]^2)/(
>               a[1, 2]^2 + b[1, 2]^2)))) || (0 < a[1, 2] < Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - 
>            b[1, 
>             1]^2] && ((b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[
>                1 - a[1, 1]^2 - a[1, 2]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == (-a[1, 1] a[1, 2]^2 - 
>                2 a[1, 2] b[1, 1] b[1, 2] + a[1, 1] b[1, 2]^2)/(
>               a[1, 2]^2 + b[1, 2]^2)) || (b[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>               1 - a[1, 1]^2 - a[1, 2]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>              a[2, 2] == (-a[1, 1] a[1, 2]^2 - 
>                2 a[1, 2] b[1, 1] b[1, 2] + a[1, 1] b[1, 2]^2)/(
>               a[1, 2]^2 + b[1, 2]^2)))) || (a[1, 2] == Sqrt[
>           1 - a[1, 1]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>          b[1, 2] == -Sqrt[1 - a[1, 1]^2 - a[1, 2]^2 - b[1, 1]^2] && 
>          a[2, 2] == (-a[1, 1] a[1, 2]^2 - 2 a[1, 2] b[1, 1] b[1, 2] + 
>            a[1, 1] b[1, 2]^2)/(a[1, 2]^2 + b[1, 2]^2))) && 
>      b[2, 2] == -((-a[1, 2] b[1, 1] + a[1, 1] b[1, 2] - 
>         a[2, 2] b[1, 2])/a[1, 2]))

I don't think it is a good idea to do this for $n\ge3$.

Comment: I don't think so neither. Thanks!